# set current model to database object in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

How do you set the model to a database object in an efficient way? What is the better way to do this than below?

```
    $user = $this->User->findByPassword($password, array('fields'=>'id'));
    $this->User = new User($user["User"]["id"]);
    $this->User->read();
    print_r($this->User);
```

I've looked everywhere but i can't find it.

Comment: Do not use read(). What exactly do you want to accomplish. You probably already got all the data you will need in your `$user` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by accident. This is the one-liner i was looking for.

```
$this->User->set($this->User->findByPassword('first',$password));
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean:

```
$user = $this->User->findByPassword($password, array('fields'=>'id'));
$this->User->id = $user["User"]["id"]; //set the id
print_r($this->User);
```

Comment: Are there no simple one-liners like you have with c#? object = object.Where(id => id).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @bicycle sorry no idea about C#, but the added code is not that complex, as its just assigning the id to User model and after which you can easily fetch the related records...!

Comment: Yeah i know it's not complex but it's not right that memory is allocated ($user) just to set the object. Why not setting the object without initiating any variable.